# Django SASS processor does not update CSS files in production

Tags: css, django, sass

I am using django-sass-processor (https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor) in order to generate .css from .scss files. The css wiles were generated on the fly in production, based on the modified date of the scss file (as I understand it from the documentation). However, this on-the-fly-generation of files suddenly stopped working. I have moved my static folder to a different location, so I suspect that is a problem, but my regular static operations (collectstatic) works just fine - it's just the css file generation.

Here are the relevant variables from my settings.py:

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
      'django.contrib.humanize',
      'sass_processor',
      ....
  ]

  STATIC_ROOT = '/mnt/hd5/static/'
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = '/mnt/hd5/static/css/'

  STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
      'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
  ]
```

The following file is located in /mnt/hd5/static/css:

`stylesheet.scss`

If I look at the latest filedate it is indeed the latest version, being modified more recently than the .css files. When I run collectstatic (not even sure that is needed?), it doesn't pick up any modifications.

Is there a glaring problem that can be seen above? Or alternatively is there a way I can record/view any error that is generated in the process?

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` is where Django stores *collected* static files to serve - it's not where Django (or django-sass-processor`) will look for source files.

Similarly `SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT` is where the processor will *store* the generated CSS files - not where it will look for source SCSS files.

The file you want the processor to look for and process needs to be in one of the directories that the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` will look in.

So, if you have an app called `myapp` then your source files should be at `myapp/static/css/stylesheet.scss` - the processor will find it here and a generated CSS file will be stored in the directory set as `SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT` (this is where the `AppDirectoriesFinder` looks).

Alternatively, if you prefer not to store the source files inside a specific app, the processor will also look in any directory you have added to the [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) setting (this is where the `FileSystemFinder` looks).